# WAMPP problemas migrar sitio y BD

Tags: php, mysql, apache

actualmente poseo un portal en una maquina local con WAMPP, la cual deseo migrar a otra maquina local tambien con WAMPP.

lo unico que tome es el portal www (c:wamp/www), y su BD (C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data\bd)

la version de WAMPP es la misma, y tiene las mismas configuraciones en apache.

siendo asi al intentar loguear en mi sitio no puedo, reviso el log de errores de apache y php y no existe alguno.

estoy seguro que puede ser alguna conf de apache o la conexion a la BD pero no logro visualizar el error.

alguien podra ayudarme?

Comment: Sólo para motivos de depuración, siendo ambas versiones de WAMP iguales podrías copiar la carpeta completa de wamp desde la maquina que funciona y pegarla en la que está dando problemas (reemplazando los archivos cada vez que salga el cuadro de dialogo). Si aún así no funciona en tu otra maquina entonces tu problema no tendría nada que ver con los archivos de configuración ni con WAMP sino con cualquier otra aplicación/programa que esté interfiriendo en la maquina que está dando el problema

Comment: el log de errores de php no estaba guardando los datos. finalmente era una carpeta que no existia en el directorio fue por eso. muchas gracias ;)

Comment: De nada, me alegra que solucionaste